# How play video in Windows Phone application

Tags: video, windows-phone, avi, mpeg

How to play video on the Windows Phone telephone kept at project resources? The codec is `MPEG-1 Layer 2` and the multimedia container is `avi`. I would like to play this file in Windows Phone Page without any controls(play, pause, stop) visible. I can convert video file to any other format if this is more convienient.

What component should I use and how to bind this component to the video and then play?

Comment: without any controls visible means.. so that user can hear the sound without seeing the video?

Comment: @har07 I will edit the OP. By controls I mean play, stop, pause etc. The video should be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.aspx) control for displaying video without play/pause/stop controls :

```
<MediaElement AutoPlay="True" x:Name="mediaEl" MediaFailed="MediaEl_MediaFailed"
    Source="pathToVideoRelativeToCurrentPage.mp4"/>
```

Good practice when using MediaElement control is to handle MediaFailed event. Because when loading media file fails (f.e. file not found due to wrong path), ME doesn't throw exception but raise MediaFailed event instead.

List of media format supported by silverlight version of MediaElement control can be found in [this MSDN post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189080%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).